# update object in meteor only in server code, not via ddp api

Tags: meteor

I am using meteor. I would like to permit update to objects in `picks` collection only via `call` calls from client to server and not via the usual `DDP` api.
In that way I can control the exact update function in the server and do there some complex permissions check for each update.
Is the check `Meteor.isServer` good for this case, or is it not doing what I think?

```
Picks = new Mongo.Collection("picks");

Picks.allow({
      insert: function (userId, pick) {
        return userId && pick.owner === userId;
      },
      update: function (userId, pick, fields, modifier) {
        return Meteor.isServer;
      },
      remove: function (userId, pick) {
        if (userId !== pick.owner)
          return false;

        return true;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow and deny rules [*only apply to updates from a client*](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow), which makes things much simpler than you're imagining.

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, all you need to do is return `false` from all of the `Picks.allow` functions, so that no client writes will be accepted.  This won't do anything to prevent you writing to the collection from the server side, so provided you have appropriate validation in your `Meteor.methods`, you're free to do whatever you want to the collection within them as they're server-side code, and just have the user invoke updates via `Meteor.call`.